# Нужно написать программу на С++ и PYTHON , часть уже сделал , но нужна помощь закончить

Tags: c++, python

Программа должна быть написана на С++, и на этой основе сделать тоже самое на PYTHON . Условие " *Написать программу, которая находит все симметричные числа в интервале [n....m] ,которые возводя в квадрат, получается тоже симметричное число. Интервал вводит сам пользователь. ЗАДАЧУ НУЖНО РЕШИТЬ ИСПОЛЬЗУЮ ФУНКЦИЮ, КОТОРАЯ ОПРЕДЕЛЯЕТ ПРИНАДЛЕЖНОСТЬ ЧИСЕЛ К СИММЕТРИЧНЫМ ЧИСЛАМ.  Если числа не найдены в введенном интервале, программа должна выдать соответствующее послание. Должна быть возможность выполнить программу повторно , не выходя из программы.*"

**На С++ я все написал и он засчитан!**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool sim(int sk)                          
{
    int sk2=sk, rez=0, cip;

    do
     {
         cip = sk2 % 10;                   
         rez = (rez * 10) + cip;            
         sk2 = sk2 / 10;
     } while (sk2 != 0);
     if(sk==rez) return true;
    else return false;
}
int main()
{
    int ok;
    int n, m;

    cout << " Найдем симметричные числа в интервале [n...m] " << endl;
    do{
    bool rez=true;
    cout << "Введите n" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Введите m" << endl;
    cin >> m;
    cout << "Симметричные числа:" << endl;
    for(int i=n;i<=m;i++)                                     
    {                                                         
        if(sim(i*i)==true) {                                  
        cout << i << "*" << i << "=" << i*i << endl;
        rez=false; }
    }
    if(rez) cout << "Нет результатов!" << endl;
       cout << "Продолжить(1), закончить(0)?" << endl;
        cin >> ok;
        }while(ok==1);
return 0;
}
```

**На PYTHON тоже готово, но он не засчитан, так как по словам препода, нету той самой функции , которая определяет принадлежность чисел к симметричным числам, и что я должен был сделать программу с таким же алгоритмам (не кодом, а алгоритмам) как в С++. Вообщем я в шоке и прошу помощи с этим, я уже многое перепробовал.**

Код на PYTHON

```
def sim(s):
    for i in range(n, m+1):
        if str(i) == str(i)[::-1] and str(i*i) == str(i*i)[::-1]:
            s = True 
            print( 'Симметричные числа :' )
            print (str(i) + '*' + str(i) + '=' + str(i*i))         
        if not s:
            s = False
            print (" Нет результата ")
            break
ok = 1
while ok == 1:
    print('Найдем все симметричные числа в интервале [n...m] ,')
    s = False
    n, m = int(input('Введите n\n')), int(input('Введите m\n'))
    sim(s)
    ok = int(input(" Продолжить (1), закончить (0)?" ))
```

Comment: Помощи какого рода? Не можешь три строчки в отдельную функцию вынести? В с++ функция возвращает тру или нет, а в питоне ничего не возвращает. Вот что нужно исправить.

Comment: для питон как японский, нам его засунули в программу обучение для галочку, но изза него не могу сдать некоторые программы, и суть не в строчках, а вообще во всей программе

Comment: Ну они действительно отличаются. не знаю зачем мог бы понадобиться "такой же алгоритм", но если просят "такой же", то цикл с перебором интервала n-m надо вынести из функции в основную процедуру, а функцию вызывать для каждого отдельного квадрата

Comment: Ну и надпись "Симметричные числа" в питоновском варианте выводиться перед каждым числом, а в C один раз для всей проверки интервала

Comment: цикл с перебором интервала n-m надо вынести из функции в основную процедуру тоже делал, однако программа не шла уже, там что то не так с синтаксом, а что, черт его знает этот питон

Answer (score -1, accepted):

это опять я)
Вот что у меня получилось:
функция возвращает только True или False для одного числа, и вне её уже происходит проверка каждого числа на интервале этой функцией

```
def is_symmetric(num) -> bool:
    return str(num) == str(num)[::-1] and str(num*num) == str(num*num)[::-1]

while True:
    flag = True
    print('Найдем все симметричные числа на интервале [n...m]')
    n, m = int(input('Введите n\n')), int(input('Введите m\n'))
    print('Симметричные числа:')
    for num in range(n, m+1):
        if is_symmetric(num):
            print(str(num) + '*' + str(num) + '=' + str(num * num))
            flag = False
    if flag:
        print('Нет результатов!')
    x = input('Продолжить (1), закончить (0)?\n')
    if x == '1':
        continue
    elif x == '0':
        break
```

Надеюсь это то, что требуется